# Получить значение с .ashx

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Здравствуйте,у меня есть обработчик ashx,который загружает на сервер изображения

```
public class fileuploadHandler : IHttpHandler {
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
                string fname = context.Server.MapPath("~/img/" + "111"+file.FileName);
                file.SaveAs(fname);
            }
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("File(s) Uploaded Successfully!");
    }
```

Затем с помощью jquery формируется ajax.Подскажите,пожалуйста,как я могу получить переменную fname c ashx, в jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Buttonsave").click(function (evt) {
            var fileUpload = $("#FileUpload1").get(0);
            var files = fileUpload.files;

            var data = new FormData();
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
            }

            var options = {};
            options.url = "fileuploadHandler.ashx";
            options.type = "POST";
            options.data = data;
            options.contentType = false;
            options.processData = false;
            options.success = function (result) { alert(result); };
            options.error = function (err) { alert(err.statusText); };

            $.ajax(options);

            evt.preventDefault();
        });
        var fname=.....//Here to receive a variable 
    });
```

Заранее большое спасибо за помощь

Comment: zkolya, я же привел вам пример [в вашем прошлом вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419050/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-asp-net-ajax). вы пробовали подправить свой код (хотя бы для работы с одним файлом)?

Comment: @PashaPash,Не затруднит ли Вас подсказать,почему подчеркивает Select            context.Response.Write(String.Join("|", filenames.Select(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute)));